# BeautifulSoup выдаёт "?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть беда с BeautifulSoup4: хочу получить данные из тега, `id` которого - `td_rem_week_label`, но консоль выдаёт "?"...

Вот код:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
url = "https://olegon.ru/summer.htm"
page = requests.get(url)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml') 
weeksToSummer = soup.find(id='td_rem_week_label') 

print(weeksToSummer.text)
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глянуть в код, который возвращается:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="Сколько осталось до лета? (точный счетчик дней, часов минут, секунд)" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://olegon.ru/summer.htm" />
<title>Сколько осталось до лета? (точный счетчик дней, часов минут, секунд)</title>
<script>

function fr( str, minlen )
{
  var s = new String( str );

  if( s.length<minlen && s.search( /\./ ) == -1 ) s += ".";
  while( s.length<minlen ) s += "0";

  return s;
}

function fl( str, minlen )
{
  var s = new String( str );

  while( s.length<minlen ) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

function GetDateStr( date )
{
  var s;
  s = fl( date.getDate(), 2 ) + "/";
  s += fl( date.getMonth()+1, 2 ) + "/";
  s += date.getFullYear() + " ";
  s += fl( date.getHours(), 2 ) + ":";
  s += fl( date.getMinutes(), 2 ) + ":";
  s += fl( date.getSeconds(), 2 ) + ".";
  s += fl( date.getMilliseconds(), 3 );

  return s;
}

function Format( expr, decplaces )
{
  var str = "" + Math.round( eval( expr ) * Math.pow( 10,decplaces ) );
  while( str.length <= decplaces ) str = "0" + str;
  var decpoint = str.length - decplaces;
  return str.substring( 0, decpoint ) + "." + str.substring( decpoint, str.length );
}

function GetVal( now, begin, end )
{
  var processed = now.getTime() - begin.getTime();
  var total = end.getTime() - begin.getTime();

  return 100*processed/total;
}

function GetStrPerc( val )
{
  if( val < 0 )
  {
    return "0%";
  }
  else if( val > 100 )
  {
    return "100%";
  }
  else
  {
    return Format( val, 14 ) + "%";
  }
}

function GetStr( val, label_before, label_after, label_now )
{
  if( val < 0 )
  {
    return label_before;
  }
  else if( val > 100 )
  {
    return label_after;
  }
  else
  {
    return GetStrPerc( val ) + label_now;
  }
}

//

var now;

function Period( begin, end, idPrefix, sBefore, sPeriod, sAfter )
{
  val = GetVal( now, begin, end );
  str = GetStr( val, sBefore, sAfter, sPeriod );

  document.getElementById( idPrefix+"l" ).innerHTML = str;
  document.getElementById( idPrefix+"p" ).style.width = GetStrPerc( val );
}

function Remain( end, idPrefix )
{
  var remain = end.getTime() - now.getTime();

  SetRemain( idPrefix+"sec", remain, 1000 );
  SetRemain( idPrefix+"min", remain, 1000*60 );
  SetRemain( idPrefix+"hour", remain, 1000*60*60 );
  SetRemain( idPrefix+"day", remain, 1000*60*60*24 );
  SetRemain( idPrefix+"week", remain, 1000*60*60*24*7 );
}

function SetTime( time, idLabel, sLabel )
{
  if( !sLabel ) sLabel = "%s";
  sLabel = sLabel.replace( /%s/, GetDateStr( time ) );
  if( document.getElementById( idLabel ).innerHTML != sLabel )
    document.getElementById( idLabel ).innerHTML = sLabel;
}

function OnInterval()
{
  now = new Date();

  var sNow = "сейчас: "+GetDateStr( now );
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  if( now.getMonth() < 7 ) --year;

  var str, strperc, val, begin, end;

  //autumn
  begin = new Date( year, 8, 1 );
  end = new Date( year, 11, 1 );
  Period( begin, end, "td_progress1", "осень еще не началась.", " осени завершено!", "осень уже позади." );

  //winter
  begin = new Date( year, 11, 1 );
  end = new Date( year+1, 2, 1 );
  Period( begin, end, "td_progress2", "зима еще не началась.<br>зимы не будет! ;)", " зимы завершено!", "зима уже позади." );

  //spring
  begin = new Date( year+1, 2, 1 );
  end = new Date( year+1, 5, 1 );
  Period( begin, end, "td_progress3", "весна еще не началась.", " весны завершено!", "весна уже позади. ура! уже лето!" );

  //main
  begin = new Date( year, 8, 1 )
  end = new Date( year+1, 5, 1 );
  Period( begin, end, "td_progress", "лето еще не закончилось!!! :-))) не теряй времени!!!", " нелетнего периода завершено!", "лето уже началось!!! :-))) не теряй времени!!!" );

  //now
  SetTime( now, "td_now", "сейчас: %s" );

  //begin
  SetTime( begin, "td_begin" );

  //end
  SetTime( end, "td_end" );

  //remain
  Remain( end, "td_rem_" );
}

function SetRemain( id, remain, one )
{
  document.getElementById( id+"_label" ).innerHTML = Format( remain / one,  Math.floor( Math.log( one )*Math.LOG10E ) );
  document.getElementById( id+"p" ).style.width = GetStrPerc( (remain%one)*100/one );
}

function DrawProgress( idPrefix )
{
  var output = "<div id=\""+idPrefix+"\"><div class=\"progress\" id=\""+idPrefix+"p\"></div></div>";
  document.write( output );
}

function DrawLabel( idPrefix )
{
  var output = "<div class=\"label\" id=\""+idPrefix+"l\"></div>";
  document.write( output );
}

function DrawLabProgress( idPrefix )
{
  DrawProgress( idPrefix );
  DrawLabel( idPrefix );
}

function Init()
{
  OnInterval();             
  setInterval("OnInterval()", 10 );
}

</script>

<style>
body, table {font-family: arial;}

.progress{overflow:hidden; height:12px;}
.label{text-align:center;}

#td_progressp {background-color:#88ff88;}
#td_progress {background-color:#8888FF;}

#td_progress1p {background-color:#8888FF;}
#td_progress1 {background-color:#FF8888;}

#td_progress2p {background-color:#FFFF88;}
#td_progress2 {background-color:#8888FF;}

#td_progress3p {background-color:#88FF88;}
#td_progress3 {background-color:#FFFF88;}

#td_rem_weekp, #td_rem_dayp, #td_rem_hourp, #td_rem_minp, #td_rem_secp {background-color:#888888;}
#td_rem_week, #td_rem_day, #td_rem_hour, #td_rem_min, #td_rem_sec {background-color:#eeeeee;}

</style>
</head>
<body onload="Init();">

<p class=MsoNormal style='text-align:center'><b><span style='font-size:20.0pt;font-family:Arial;color:red'>Ждем лето!</span></b></p>



<a style="font-size:10px" href="https://olegon.ru/showthread.php?t=6381">Другие интересности</a>
  <table style="border-spacing:0;padding:0;border:0;width:100%;height:60%">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <table>
          <col><col><col style="width:90%">
          <tr><td colspan=3>До лета осталось...</td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>недель:</td><td id=td_rem_week_label style="text-align:right">?</td>
            <td>
              <script>DrawProgress( "td_rem_week" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>дней:</td><td id=td_rem_day_label style="text-align:right">?</td>
            <td>
              <script>DrawProgress( "td_rem_day" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>часов:</td><td id=td_rem_hour_label style="text-align:right">?</td>
            <td>
              <script>DrawProgress( "td_rem_hour" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>минут:</td><td id=td_rem_min_label style="text-align:right">?</td>
            <td>
              <script>DrawProgress( "td_rem_min" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>секунд:</td><td id=td_rem_sec_label style="text-align:right">?</td>
            <td>
              <script>DrawProgress( "td_rem_sec" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="border-spacing:0;padding:0;border:0;width:100%">
          <tr>
           <td style="text-align:left" id=td_begin></td>
            <td style="text-align:center" id=td_now></td>
            <td style="text-align:right" id=td_end></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <script>DrawLabProgress( "td_progress" );</script>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width:100%;border-spacing:5px;padding:5px">
          <tr style="height:10px;vertical-align:top">
            <td style="width:33%">
              <script>DrawLabProgress( "td_progress1" );</script>
            </td>
            <td style="width:33%">
              <script>DrawLabProgress( "td_progress2" );</script>
            </td>
            <td style="width:33%">
              <script>DrawLabProgress( "td_progress3" );</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<br>
<br>

<div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:100%;margin:10px" id="someshit"></div>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
if (Math.random()<0.1){
(function(w, d, n, s, t) {
w[n] = w[n] || [];
w[n].push(function() {
Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
blockId: "R-A-19006-40",
renderTo: "someshit",
async: true
});
});
t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s = d.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "//an.yandex.ru/system/context.js";
s.async = true;
t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
})(this, this.document, "yandexContextAsyncCallbacks");
}else{
var g = document.createElement("ins");
g.className = "adsbygoogle";
g.style.display = "block";
g.style.textAlign = "center";
g.setAttribute("data-ad-client", "ca-pub-8894202013852067");
g.setAttribute("data-ad-slot", "3529193074");
g.setAttribute("data-ad-format", "auto");
g.setAttribute("data-full-width-responsive", "true");
document.getElementById("someshit").appendChild(g);
if (
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("YandexBot") == -1)&&
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Googlebot") == -1)&&
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Lighthouse") == -1)){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});}
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
if (!window['adsbygoogle'].loaded) {
document.body.innerHTML = 'Отключите блокировщик рекламы, пожалуйста.';
}});
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

увидеть много букв, не растерятся, глянуть на панель разработчика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

понять, что "?" - правильный ответ, т.к. сайт использует js для расчета и вывода, и что легче и проще сделать это самому:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
summer_begin = datetime(2021, 6, 1)

weeks_to_summer = (summer_begin - now).days / 7
print(f'До лета осталось {weeks_to_summer} недель.')
```

выведет

```
До лета осталось 6.857142857142857 недель.
```

Comment: Спасибо что помогли, но как мне получить именно это число ?

Comment: @RoToN добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное,вы мне очень помогли!